# my code is not working in updating record in django

Tags: python, django

I am making a employee management system in django. i have created all the fields create, read, delete and filter but I am unable to write update field.please someone help me..

This is my views.py file

```
 def update_emp(request,emp_id=0):
    context={}
    obj= get_object_or_404(Employee, id=emp_id)
    # obj=Employee.objects.get(id=emp_id)
    form = employeeForm(request.POST or None, instance = obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/'+id)
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'update_emp.html' ,context)
```

This is my urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path , include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('all_emp', views.all_emp, name = 'all_emp'),
    path('add_emp', views.add_emp, name = 'add_emp'),
    path('remove_emp', views.remove_emp, name = 'remove_emp'),
    path('remove_emp/<int:emp_id>', views.remove_emp, name = 'remove_emp'),
    path('filter_emp', views.filter_emp, name = 'filter_emp'),
    # path('update_emp', views.update_emp, name = 'update_emp'),
    path('update_emp/<int:id>', views.update_emp, name='update_emp'),
   
    
]
```

This is my  update_emp.html file

```
 <div class="main">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
```

This is my forms.py file

```
    from django import forms

class employeeForm(forms.Form):
    fname=forms.CharField(label="Value1",required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    lname=forms.CharField(label="Value2",required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `forms.ModelForm` if you want to save a model instance.
Your employee form is not related to a model, so it has nothing to save.

You should try something like that.

```py
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Employee
    fields = ['fname', 'lastname']
```